# Extract previous price from Amazon Page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I used BeautifulSoup in Python for extract the **previous price** on an Amazon page, but the code that i used prints the current price and not the previous price.

I tryed:

```
priceold = soup.find(class_="a-span12 a-color-secondary a-size-base").get_text()
```

The page is this https://www.amazon.it/dp/B08LQ3WPWS/ and i need to extract 799,99€ (the previous price).

The HTML code on the page is:

```
<tr><td class="a-color-secondary a-size-base a-text-right a-nowrap">Prezzo consigliato:</td><td class="a-span12 a-color-secondary a-size-base">
<span class="a-price a-text-price a-size-base" data-a-size="b" data-a-strike="true" data-a-color="secondary"><span class="a-offscreen">799,99€</span><span aria-hidden="true">799,99€</span></span>
```

I need **only one** 799,99€. How can i select it correctly with BeautifulSoup?

I think i need to select class **a-span12 a-color-secondary a-size-base** and at the same time class **a-offscreen**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:-

```
#get price block
price_block=soup.find('span',class_='a-price a-text-price a-size-base')

#get previous price within price block
previous_price=price_block.find('span',class_='a-offscreen')
print(previous_price.text)
```

Comment: Thanks Kamalesh S, but it prints the current price, 759€ :( I need 799€, the previous price

Comment: I have tested the code, it gives 799,99€ as the output. I used selenium, are you using that or the requests library? Doesn't know if it really makes a difference

Comment: it works, my mistake! Thanks :)

Comment: No worries, you're welcome!!